# define function with strings as parameter

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

why when we define a function with strings as parameter we don't need quotation marks, but when we use it we need quotation marks? thanks!

for example,

```
def shout(word):
    shout_word = word + '!!!'
```

(here we don't have quotation marks for 'word')

```
shout_word('abd')
```

but here we need '' for abd..

I already go through some materials online, but probably my question is too details or too basic so it seems no body asked it before. Thank you for your help!! it's important for me to learn python!

Comment: When you define the function, you write the parameter as a variable name. When you call the function, you pass a value. The effect is like an assignment; `word = 'abd'`

Comment: Why the downvote? The Q is very clear. It's incredibly basic but no question is too basic for SO.

Answer (score 3):

The token 'word' declares a parameter of the shout function. At this point, it is not clear whether it is a string or not - its just a variable name. Its type will be checked at the point where your code tries to add '!!!' to it. '!!!' is a string literal and the interpreter will check whether the runtime type of 'word' supports having strings added to it.

It is important you understand the difference between variable names and variable literals when learning any programming language.

Comment: yes.. you are right, I need to understand it better. Just start to learn python. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Because word isn't explicitly defined as a string in the function, it's just a variable. Passing 'abc' into the function means word gets assigned a value of 'abc'.

Answer (score 2):

It's because function parameters are also variables. If you enclose the string parameter for a function in quotation marks, e.g. `"word"`, then it's not a parameter anymore.

Comment: yes... it's my first week to use python. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in programming languages, whenever we define a method we use a parameter name as a placeholder. This helps us generalize the problem, and allow our function to work on different data.

Here you have a method that needs to take a string, and denotes this using the variable *word*. We want this method to work for any string we give the method **shout_word()**, so we generalize with this variable name.

Whenever you call the method, like when you execute **shout_word("abc")**, the "abc" is in quotation marks because we are passing a value into our parameter *word*.

[Here is some more notation for you on method definitions in Python!](https://www.w3resource.com/python/python-user-defined-functions.php)

Answer (score 0):

Word in the first instance is not a string, it's a variable named "word". In the second instance "abd" is a string literal

Comment: thank you!! I am still pretty new here! thank you for answering my question!